# How can I pick an element from each 1D list inside a 2D list according to a list of indices?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The i-th element of our list of indices indicate the index of the i-th 1D list in the 2D list that we want to know.

If our 2D list and list of indices looks like this:

```
a = [[1,7,3],[9,0,8]]

list_ix = [1, 0]
```

The desired result is [7,9].

Currently I do this by using a loop like below:

```
res = []
for i in range(len(list_ix)):
    res.append(a[i][list_ix[i]])
```

but this looks messy in the actual code.

Is there a better way to do this? I'd appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be done this way:

```
res = [a[idx][element] for idx, element in enumerate(list_ix)]
```

Read more about enumerate here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` function:

```
a = [[1,7,3],[9,0,8]]    
list_ix = [1, 0]

out = [l[i] for i, l in zip(list_ix, a)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) which lets you both to get a value from a list and track your current position.

```
a = [[1,7,3],[9,0,8]]

list_ix = [1, 0]

res = []
for i, outer_list_index in enumerate(list_ix):
    res.append(a[i][outer_list_index])

print(res)
```